# E2 reaction — which one is faster?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, kinetics

Will an E2 reaction that has 2 potential products go faster than one that has 3 potential products? The specific question involves both molecules below reacting with methanol. I figured it's an E2 reaction (I hope I'm right) and the question is, which one will go faster?

[image: cyclohexylbromides]

Comment: Could you provide specifics?

Comment: What are the conditions for this reaction? Only methanol is mentioned, which leads me to believe this is E1 not E2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the E1 pathway, molecule A will react faster since the intermediate is more stable than from molecule B. According to this [web site](http://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/2012/10/10/comparing-the-e1-and-e2-reactions/), the major product for A is 1,2-dimethylcyclohexene; for B, it is 1-methylcyclohexene.

For the E2 pathway, both reactions will have nearly the same rate. Depending on the orientation of the α-methyl group (cis or trans to Br), the major product is the same for cis, but for trans it will be 2,3-dimethylcyclohexene for A and 2-methylcyclohexene for B.

Comment: why is the intermediate more stable in molecule A?

Comment: The intermediate is a tertiary cation; it's more stable than a secondary cation.

Comment: But in the E2 mechanism there is no cation formed.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン It's been a while since I needed to know the difference between E1 and E2. I have them switched.

Comment: I was confused, too, and had to look it up. And now I see a comment to the question, that makes me believe your answer is absolutely on target.